# Create a data.frame with m columns and 2 rows

Tags: r

I would like to create a data.frame in R with m (a variable) number of columns (for example 30), and 2 rows and fill all the values in the data.frame initially with 0's. It seems as though data.frame populates values based on rows rather that columns, any suggestions how I can do this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 69):

Does `m` really need to be a `data.frame()` or will a `matrix()` suffice?

```
m <- matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2)
```

You can wrap a `data.frame()` around that if you need to:

```
m <- data.frame(m)
```

or all in one line: `m <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))`

Comment: And that was exactly what _I_ was going to write. +1 ;) My only addition would be to explicitly point out that `data.frame()` typically specifies data by column via its tag=value arguments.

Answer (score 40):

For completeness:

Along the lines of Chase's answer, I usually use `as.data.frame` to coerce the matrix to a data.frame:

`m <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))`

EDIT: `speed test data.frame` vs. `as.data.frame`

```
system.time(replicate(10000, data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.005   0.108   8.165 

system.time(replicate(10000, as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.759   0.048   3.802
```

Yes, it appears to be faster (by about 2 times).

Comment: what's different about your answer? is it faster?

Comment: @Eduardo it appears to be a little faster - see above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a data.frame with a certain number of rows, and you already know the column names, you can define the `make_df()` function like so:

```r
make_df <- function(nrow) {
  if (missing(nrow)) {
    nrow <- 0
  }
  
  temp_df <- data.frame(
    word = character(),
    meaning_grouping = integer(),
    part_of_speech = character(),
    phonetic = character(),
    audio = character(),
    origin = character(),
    definition = character(),
    examples = character(),
    synonyms = character(),
    antonyms = character(),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  if (nrow > 0) {
    temp_df[1:nrow,] <- NA
  }
  
  temp_df
}
```

It allows you to populate both the **column names** *and* **column classes** (e.g. character, integer, numeric etc).

To create a data.frame with 5 rows, for example:

```
make_df(nrow=5)
  word meaning_grouping part_of_speech phonetic audio origin definition examples synomyms antonyms
1 <NA>               NA           <NA>     <NA>  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2 <NA>               NA           <NA>     <NA>  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
3 <NA>               NA           <NA>     <NA>  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
4 <NA>               NA           <NA>     <NA>  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
5 <NA>               NA           <NA>     <NA>  <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

Or to create a data.frame with 0 rows:

```r
make_df()
 [1] word             meaning_grouping part_of_speech   phonetic         audio            origin           definition       examples        
 [9] synomyms         antonyms        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```